# Python 3, How to remove part of an element of a list if it contains a specific thing3

Tags: python

I have a list of data that comes in the form of lists with numbers in them. as an intermediate step to making them all integers, I need to remove all the non-number parts within the element.

> ['jeff','69','420','80085\n']

how do I check to see if **\n** is in an element and how do I remove it if it is?

> ['jeff','69','420','80085']

Is the wanted output.
 I literally don't know how to start, I can turn the numbers into integers using loops and intermediate variable but trying to identify things within them is not something i know how to do.

Comment: But `'jeff'` is not a number either. Don't you want it removed?

Comment: Please show what you've tried based on your research into this task

Comment: @Bollehenk, given that there is absolutely no code here, how is that a reasonable duplicate?

Comment: Not like del or pop because I don't wont to remove the whole element. just the stuff within them that is equal to /n

Comment: Sorry, im new to this

Comment: @AliceD Do `\n` comes always at the end of string?

Comment: yes, but luckily x.replace has fixed it entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> input = ['jeff','69','420','80085\n']
>>> output = [x.replace('\n','') for x in input]
>>> output
['jeff', '69', '420', '80085']
```

Comment: where did 80085 go speedy

Comment: oh, i didn't even know replace was a thing. Thanks so much!